<ScrollControls>, <Scroll>, and <Html> in React Three Fiber: Is it allowed to nest <Html> inside of <Scroll>
I am using  from React Three Drei. Under the Hood,  creates a HTML scroll container in front of the canvas. Then you have to nest a  Container inside the  Container. Everything you drop into the  component will be affected by Scrolling. So far so good.
What if I then directly nest  Component from @react-three/drei inside ?
Where is this  then exactly?  Is it somewhere inside or above and could this cause issues?
Actually, right now It seems to work, but I´ve read, that nesting  inside  is not a typical use case and may lead to undesired outcomes due to the nature of how these components are designed to function within the R3F/Drei ecosystem.
If it is not a good idea, I would like to know, how can I add some more Text and Images like you can see below in the About.jsx Component into my R3F Project without issues?
My code is like this:
**In App.jsx:
<Canvas>  

// some code .... 

<ScrollControls               
enabled={true}               
damping={0.1}               
horizontal={true}               
pages={3} >  
             
<Scroll>                 
<ThreeScene position={[1, 0, 0]} />             
</Scroll> 
            
</ScrollControls> 
</Canvas>

**In ThreeScene.jsx:
const ThreeScene = () =\> {
//... some code

return (
\<\>
{/\* Note: This whole group scrolls along, due to the Scrollcontainer in the parent App.jsx */}
\<group position={\[0, 0, 0\]}\>
\<LandingPage ref={ref} \>
{/* Note: Every element inside of these Child-Components of ThreeScene will follow along when scrolling \*/}
\</group\>
\<group position={\[19, 3, 0\]}\>
\<About \>
\</group\>
\<group position={\[40, 3, 0\]}\>
\<TechStack />
\</group\>
\</\>
);
};
export default ThreeScene;

**and for example in About.jsx:

const About = forwardRef(function About(props, ref) {
return (
\<\>
{/\* Note: \<Html\>: The \<Html\> component from Drei is designed to render HTML elements directly onto the canvas. These HTML elements are not part of the 3D scene but are instead rendered on top of the canvas. This is useful for overlaying UI elements, text, or other web-based content over your 3D scene. \*/}
\<Html\>
\<main className={styles.aboutWrapper}\>
\<img
className={styles.portrait}
src="/assets/images/Portrait.png"
alt=""
/\>
\<section className={styles.aboutTextSection}\>
\<h1 className={styles.aboutHeading}\>Hey\</h1\>
\<div className={styles.aboutTextBox}\>
\<p\>
orem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, maiores ut esse nulla ipsum distinctio iure veniam cum harum soluta sapiente laudantium similique possimus non labore ducimus quibusdam perspiciatis voluptatem expedita illo. Sapiente voluptates, corporis temporibus iure possimus quia commodi molestias porro sit modi.
\</p\>
\</div\>
\</section\>
\</main\>
\</Html\>
\</\>
);
});

**Thank you for looking further into this, I appreciate your help!
**
Nadja
`
